# Call another GUI within a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have 2 GUIs that I have created using qt-designer and I converted it into python - anmUi.py and anmInfoUI.py

While I am able to import both and open the `anmUi` by running the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/user_data/test/anm/versions')
import anmTool_v01a
reload(anmTool_v01a)
win = anmTool_v01a.anmUi()
win.show()
```

However I am having trouble opening the second gui - `anmInfoUI` which was to be initiated by the pushbutton in the first gui.

I tried writing in the similar format as I did for the first gui but when I tried running it with `.exec`, I got error such as `# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'exec_'`.

```
class anmUi(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None, modal = False)
        self.ui = anmUi.Ui_Migration()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.createConnections()


    def createConnections(self):
        self.connect(self.ui.pushButton_editSelected, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.editSelected)


    def editSelected(self):
        selected_item = self.ui.treeWidget_migrateAnmg.selectedItems()
        if selected_item:
            anmInfoUI.exec_()


class anmInfoUI(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None, modal = False):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, modal = modal)

        self.ui = anmInfoUI.Ui_EditInfo()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

How do I get it to run?

Comment: Please provide the code where you call `exec_` and it doesn't work (all relevant code). It is necessary to know what you are doing before anyone can help you

Comment: @three_pineapples I have edited the code in my post as seen above

Answer (score 0):

`exec_()` is something you call on the Qt application. In your case, the application is already running (else you would see no window at all) and instead you want to instantiate the new widget/window and call its `show()` method.

Comment: If you include more of your code, the minimal amount to reproduce the problem, we can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: using `show()` is not working for me... This is the python code for my first UI - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=88AuDBgc while this is for my second UI - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PJ0ZKtrA. When I tried using `show()`, though I am getting no errors, but the second UI is not shown

Comment: anmgTool does not run from the code you gave (`'QDialog' object has no attribute 'slot_cancel'`)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well, I created a function called 'slot_cancel'.. Probably you can create a quick function for it, or you can remove it in the UI code. It should work either way

Answer (score 0):

This code successfully opens the new window.

```
class anmUi(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None, modal = False)
        self.ui = Ui_Migration()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.createConnections()


    def createConnections(self):
        self.connect(self.ui.pushButton_editSelected, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.editSelected)


    def editSelected(self):
        selected_item = self.ui.treeWidget_migrateAnmg.selectedItems()
        if True:
            self.child = anmInfoUI()
            self.child.show()

    def slot_cancel(self, *args):
        pass


class anmInfoUI(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None, modal = False):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, modal = modal)

        self.ui = Ui_EditAsset()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Note the use of True (I did not want to populate your selection box). You can control whether the new window is modal or not using its flags.